# Processing user input in a python program

Tags: python, input

I am making a program that gives the user a random integer from 1 to 10 as a diameter using a list and they have to calculate the circumference of a circle using Pi as 3. In my code when a user inputs a string instead of an integer, the program asks the user to input an integer instead. If the user then inputs a correct answer, the program says it is an incorrect answer. I need the program to say it is correct.
Any chance I could get some help? here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random
turtle.speed("fastest")


pi = 3
minNumber = 4
maxNumber = 10
score = 0
listNmbers = []
a = [1,3,5,7,9]

red = random.random()
green = random.random()
blue = random.random()

num1 = random.choice(a)


def askCir(cirAnswer):
    try: 
        user = input("What is the circumference of a circle if the diameter is " + str(num1) + " and Pi is 3?")
        cirAnswer = int(user)   
    except:
        print("Please input a number only!")
        cirAnswer = 0;
        cirAanswer = askCir(cirAnswer)
    return cirAnswer
    cirAnswer = 0;
    cirAnswer = askCir(cirAnswer)



print("Welcome! What is your name??")
name = str(input())
print("Hello", name,"you need to calculate the circumference of a circle when given a diameter. To calculate the circumference, use the equasion; Pi x Diameter (Pi = 3")


def getNumbers():
    num = input("how many questions would you like to answer? (Pick between 5 and 10)")
    try:
        numbers = int(num)
    except:
        print("That is not a number!")
        return getNumbers()
    goodInput = minNumber < numbers < maxNumber

    if not goodInput:
        print ("That is not between 5 and 10. Please input an integer between 5 and 10.")
        return getNumbers()
    else:
        return numbers
numbers = getNumbers()    


for i in range(numbers):
    red = random.random()
    green = random.random()
    blue = random.random()
    turtle.color(red,green,blue)
    num1 = random.choice(a)
    correct = num1 * 3

    cirAnswer = 0;
    cirAnswer = askCir(cirAnswer)
    print(str(correct))

    if float (cirAnswer) == correct:
        print("That's Correct! Well Done")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Sorry that is incorrect")

    for k in range(correct):
        turtle.color(red,green,blue)
        drawSquare()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(150)
```

Comment: Python don't have [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization. You should call `askCir` in a loop instead of using recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because of a typo in your program.

`cirAanswer = askCir(cirAnswer)` needs to be

`cirAnswer = askCir(cirAnswer)`

Basically the new answer was being assigned to a new variable `cirAanswer` and 0 was always being returned